# Copy content from powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I am able to copy the content from powerpoint but getting an error while pasing it on another powerpoint.

Error is on this line

```
pres2.Slides.Paste Index:=pres2.Slides.Count + 1
```

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim fileNameString As String
Dim NewSlide As Slide
Dim i As Integer
Dim Nstring As String
Dim Nstring1 As String
Dim Allshape As Object

Dim pres1 As PowerPoint.Presentation, pres2 As PowerPoint.Presentation, pp As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set pp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set pp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

Set pres1 = pp.Presentations.Open(Sheet1.TextBox1.Text)
Set pres2 = pp.Presentations.Open(Sheet1.TextBox2.Text)

Set NewSlide = pres1.Slides(2)
Set Allshape = NewSlide.Shapes
Allshape.Range.Copy
  
pres2.Slides.Paste Index:=pres2.Slides.Count + 1
```

Comment: Maybe you could include what the error is that you are getting?

Comment: Error - Run time error '-2147188160. Slides (unknown mumber): Invalid request. Clipboard is empty

Comment: no great answer for you, buy maybe this will help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56612747/how-to-copy-powerpoint-sections-to-a-new-presentation-using-vba

Comment: I/O operations (copy, paste, open file, save, etc.) often run more slowly that your code. There are many answers to this problem, search on _vba clipboard timing_.

Comment: Doesn't this (pres2.Slides.Count) count the number of slides in the presentation and the  "+1" goes beyond the number of slides?